# New Gaming PC issue

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

Im still trying to build my first gaming PC. So far I was able to Install windows but the OS freezes and crashes with BSOD Machine_Check_Exception while attempting to install drivers and updates. As I attempted a fresh install, I cleared all the drives. Now the install program will barely start without BSOD. While attempting to troubleshoot I found on MSI's website that my model number of RAM isn't supported, but there are other models from skill that are supported. Could this be my problem? The BSOD came faster and faster. All the parts showed no compatibility issues on pcpartpicker.com. Below is a list of components

Also Currently I don't have the GPU installed. I figured if the PC didn't work without it then it wouldn't work with it. I have already had the MOBO replaced thinking that was the problem.

-MSI B150 PC Mate MOBO 
-Intel i7 6700k 
-G skill Ripjaw V 8gb (2x4) RAM 
-Corsair 650watt Power Supply 
-Gigabyte GTX 1070 GPU -SSD and HDD

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A motherboard manufacture, not listing a specific model of memory, does not mean its not compatible.  The memory you have purchased is indeed compatible with your motherboard.  Your problem is some other component.  Verify the modules are not defective by testing them with something like MemTestx86

Comment: There should be four numbers in hex notation at the upper left corner of the blue screen. What are they?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan There were no notations.

Answer (score 0):

According to a couple of tech websites MCE's (Machine check exception) normal causes are:

1. Overclocking
2. Incorrectly fitted heatsink/Fans
3. Overload of powersupply

I'm going to work on the principle 1) hasn't been done.

2) I would make sure your heat sink is in contact with your cpu and is spinning. Make sure you have thermal paste applied correctly (Not a lot, just a decent amount in the middle and let the pressure of the heat sink spread it.)

3) Without the graphics card as you mentioned the powersupply should be able to cope with the load perfectly fine. Even with your card it should be fine (I run an i7, gtx 970, 2x HDDs and 1x ssd with a 750)